# Unity3D: террэйн из карты высот

Tags: unity3d, 3d, map, procedural-generation

Генерируется карта высот с определенным разрешением. В данный момент карта строится из тайлов, расположенных на данных высотах.

Необходимо построить террэйн, чтобы карта смотрелась более натуралистично, а не как в Майнкрафте.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, внутренний или внешний API, прием, которые бы позволили решить данную задачу.

Answer (score 1):

Где-то год назад, я экспериментировал с генерацией террейна по карте высот SRTM для своего проекта (ActionStreetMap). Карта разбивалась на тайлы заданного размера, задавался heightmap resolution для стандартного террейна, далее с помощью билинейной интерполяции для каждой вершины террейна находилось значение высоты. Однако, данный подход оказался затратным с точки зрения перфоманса: для приемлимого результата необходимо было использовать либо очень высокое разрешение террейна, либо уменьшать размер тайла. Также профайлер показал, что создание/удаление террейна весьма затратная операция.

Как результат, я отказался от встроенного террейна в пользу кастомного меша в low poly стиле.

Comment: Хм. Видимо да - придется генерировать собственный меш,

Answer (score 0):

Вы террейн хотите создать стандартный на базе карты высот? Если у вас есть карта высот по тайлам то можно эту карту в фотошопе размыть и по ней попробовать еще раз построить)

Comment: Да, мне нужен стандартный террэйн или хотя бы меш. Сгладить существующий не решение (хотя оно и так производится после генерации), т.к. тайлы останутся - пусть и не так дискретно по высоте, как в майнкрафт.